# Задача про воду накапливающуюся в профиле острова

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять как реализировать решение этой задачи.Я догадываюсь,что надо взять несколько самый высоких чисел,и уже от них вычитать меньшие числа,тем самым узнав воду.Но я не понимаю как это закодить на Python.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компьютерная игра происходит в двумерном мире, который состоит из
блоков 1 на 1 (метр).
Острова игроков - это наборы столбцов различной высоты из блоков (камней).
Во время сильных дождей все низины островов заполняются водой.
По ландшафта островов, определите объем воды, который накапливается на каждом
острове.
Входные данные - стандартный ввод.
Входные данные:

- в первой строке записано натуральное число N (0 ≤ N ≤ 15) - количество
  столбцов, которые задают ландшафт острова.
- во второй строке N натуральных чисел Hᵢ (0 ≤ Hᵢ ≤ 109
  ) - высоты столбцов
  одного острова.
  Выходные данные:
- выведите одно число - объем воды накопленный на данном острове (количество
  блоков занятых водой).

> ```
> Input  
> 11  
> 2 5 2 3 6 9 3 1 3 4 6
>
> Output  
> 18
> ```

Comment: Я минус чисто за заголовок поставил.

Comment: Так-то это уникальный заголовок) Неуникальный создать нельзя)

Comment: Фиксируете факты возрастания/убывания, попутно считая объём между локальными максимумами

Comment: В чем мой заголовок плох?

Comment: Заголовок плох тем, что его нет. Он ничего не говорит о сути вашего вопроса. Python нужно перенести в теги. В итоге ваш заголовок «Задача». Ну ок.

Comment: C локальными максимумами решение неверное. Контрпример: 10 1 5 1 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть 2 указателя, левый и правый, идут навстречу друг другу.
Также храним известные нам максимумы, при проходе справа и слева.
Зная их, мы можем точно сказать, сколько воды остаётся в конкретном столбце.

```
def solve(profile):
    if not profile:
        return 0
    l, r = 0, len(profile) - 1
    max_l, max_r = profile[l], profile[r]
    water = 0
    while l < r:
        if max_l >= max_r:
            water += max_r - profile[r]
            r -= 1

            max_r = max(max_r, profile[r])
        else:
            water += max_l - profile[l]
            l += 1

            max_l = max(max_l, profile[l])

    return water


print(solve([101, 1, 1, 2, 1, 101])) # 399
print(solve([2, 5, 2, 3, 6, 9, 3, 1, 3, 4, 6])) # 18
print(solve([1, 2, 3, 4, -11019, 4, 3, 2, 1])) # 11023
print(solve([])) # 0
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Я поправил задачу.11 - это количество столбцов в длину,а 2 5 2 3 6 9 3 1 3 4 6 это сами столбцы

Comment: Ааа, ну тогда понятно)